# My write( ) function is not working, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, fopen, fwrite

So, im new to coding and im making a registration system for a fictional hospital, that gets the user name, the procedure they had and the date, after that it sum some days to it( to calculate return) and then write on a .txt file, but the write part is not working, how can i solve it? sorry that the prints and variables are on portuguese.

```
def cadastrar(arq, nomep , proc , x, y, z, w):
    datas = datetime.strptime(w, '%Y-%m-%d')
    l = 0
    m = 0
    n = 0
    o = 0
    p = 0
    try:
        a = open(arq, 'r+')
        for linha in a:
            dados = linha.split(';')
            if dados[1] in ['Procedimento X']:
                l = datas + \
                    timedelta(days = 15)
                m = datas + \
                    timedelta(days = 152)
                n = datas + \
                    timedelta(days = 304)
                o = datas + \
                    timedelta(days = 456)
                try:
                    a.write(f'{nomep};{proc};{x}-{y}-{z}\n;{l};{m};{n};{o}')
                except:
                    print('\033[31mErro ao escrever.\033[m')
                else:
                    print(f'\033[92m{nomep} foi cadastrado com sucesso.\033[m')
                    a.close()
    finally:
        print('')
```

I want it to write on the txt file but suddently it just stopped working and idk why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should probably use the `with open():` syntax instead of `a = open()` so that the file is always closed, even if the program crashes.

Comment: you should not do  "except: " with a single print inside: the normal language behavior is to describe precisely the error that is taking place an d where it is: you are supresing that output.

Comment: supressing an error in a `except` statement makes sense when you have a larger project that has to be resilient and keep running despite errors: and in those, the correct behavior is still log the exception trace. Or, otherwise, for expected errors that are known before hand and safe to ignore. Neither is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
a = open(arq, 'r+')
```

to

```
a = open(arq, 'w+')
```

Comment: it didnt work :(